# Yum cannot find any packages on RHEL

Tags: redhat, yum, rhel7

I have two servers, both running RHEL 7, with very similar setup. Recently any package I try to find on server A fails like this:

```
[user@serverA ~]$ sudo yum install openldap-servers openldap-clients
Loaded plugins: langpacks, product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager
No package openldap-servers available.
No package openldap-clients available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

But the same command on server B finds the package just fine.

I looked further into this, and it seems to be because some time ago, I tried to uninstall `pyOpenSSL`, which caused erasing the following packages:

```
Sep 27 18:12:14 Erased: rhn-check-2.0.2-17.el7.noarch
Sep 27 18:12:14 Erased: yum-rhn-plugin-2.0.1-9.el7.noarch
Sep 27 18:12:14 Erased: rhn-setup-2.0.2-17.el7.noarch
Sep 27 18:12:14 Erased: rhnsd-5.0.13-7.el7.x86_64
Sep 27 18:12:14 Erased: abrt-console-notification-2.1.11-48.el7.x86_64
Sep 27 18:12:14 Erased: abrt-cli-2.1.11-48.el7.x86_64
Sep 27 18:12:14 Erased: abrt-addon-vmcore-2.1.11-48.el7.x86_64
Sep 27 18:12:14 Erased: rhn-client-tools-2.0.2-17.el7.noarch
Sep 27 18:12:14 Erased: abrt-tui-2.1.11-48.el7.x86_64
Sep 27 18:12:14 Erased: abrt-addon-pstoreoops-2.1.11-48.el7.x86_64
Sep 27 18:12:14 Erased: abrt-addon-python-2.1.11-48.el7.x86_64
Sep 27 18:12:14 Erased: rhnlib-2.5.65-4.el7.noarch
Sep 27 18:12:15 Erased: abrt-addon-kerneloops-2.1.11-48.el7.x86_64
Sep 27 18:12:15 Erased: abrt-addon-ccpp-2.1.11-48.el7.x86_64
Sep 27 18:12:15 Erased: abrt-addon-xorg-2.1.11-48.el7.x86_64
Sep 27 18:12:15 Erased: abrt-dbus-2.1.11-48.el7.x86_64
Sep 27 18:12:15 Erased: abrt-python-2.1.11-48.el7.x86_64
Sep 27 18:12:15 Erased: abrt-2.1.11-48.el7.x86_64
Sep 27 18:12:15 Erased: libreport-plugin-rhtsupport-2.1.11-38.el7.x86_64
Sep 27 18:12:15 Erased: redhat-access-insights-1.0.13-2.el7.noarch
Sep 27 18:12:15 Erased: pyOpenSSL-0.13.1-3.el7.x86_64
```

I tried to download the rpm for all these packages using `yumdownloader` on Server B, move them to Server A, and reinstall all of them. But I still get the same error.

Any idea how I can fix this?

Comment: What is the output of `yum repolist`? You may have unconfigured your repositories and you need to readd them using `subscription-manager`:

Comment: yep, provide this info please: cat /etc/yum.repos.d/*.repo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in the comments, try comparing the repolist configured on server A and server B.

This post walks through how to use the `yum repolist` command:
https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/centos-fedora-redhat-yum-repolist-command-tolist-package-repositories/

Once you've identified the missing repos, you can then add them using:

`yum-config-manager --add-repo *http://www.example.com/example.repo*`

and then enable them using:

`yum-config-manager --enable *repository_id*`

For more about the yum config manager commands related to repository management, see the Redhat documentation for Adding, Enabling, Disabling repos with Yum: 
https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/sec-Managing_Yum_Repositories.html